# Finding voltage between two points in space

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vectors, potential, voltage

If electric field vector is defines as :
$\vec{E} = \frac{V_0x^2}{a^3} \vec{i_x} + \frac{V_0y}{a^2} \vec{i_y} $    where $V_0 $ and $a$ are known constants, $\vec{i_x}$ and $\vec{i_y}$ unit vectors of $x$ and $y$ axis , find the voltage between points $A(a, 7a, 3a)$ and $B(4a, \sqrt{7}a, 6a)$. I know i can integrate electric field on $x$ and $y$ axis ( $z$ axis is left out since field does not spread in that direction). My approach seems to be correct, according to the textbook solution. What I don't get is why the textbook says that on $x$ axis $\vec{dx}= \vec{dl}$ and on $y$ axis $\vec{dy}= \vec{dl}$. After this is known, the task becomes simple integral since $\vec{dx} * \vec{i_x} = dx $ and $\vec{dy} * \vec{i_y} = dy $. My original plan was to find projections of $\vec{dl}$ on $x$ and $y$ axes but it appears that is unnecessary. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the electric field is conservative, you can integrate along any path between the specified points to obtain the potential.  All paths will yield the same answer.  This makes it easier, because you can pick any path that is convenient for you - or easiest to integrate.  Recall that a conservative field is defined by:

$$ \nabla \times E = 0$$

So one possible approach, as your textbook suggests, is to first do an integral along x, and then a separate integral along y - this path involves rectilinear motion - it has no curves.    For this reason it's an easy integral.

If the fields were not conservative, you wouldn't be able to arbitrarily pick a path and integrate.  The problem would have to specify long which path to integrate, and if the specified path had any curvature to it, then you'd have to perform the decomposition as you've suggested.  There's nothing wrong your approach of decomposition - that's the most general method.

Comment: Oh yes, I completely forgot about that.. Thanks :D